# How to include files in icarus verilog?

Tags: mips, verilog, cpu-architecture, iverilog, icarus

I know the basic `include "filename.v" command. But, I am trying to include a module which is in another folder. Now, that module further includes other modules present in the same folder. But, when I try to run the module on the most top-level, I am getting an error.

```
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\MIPS>iverilog mips.v
./IF/stage_if.v:2: Include file instruction_memory_if.v not found
No top level modules, and no -s option.
```

Here, I am trying to make a MIPS processor, which is contained in the file "mips.v". The first statement of this file is "`include "IF/stage_if.v". And, in the IF folder, there are numerous files present which I have included in stage_if.v, one of which is "instruction_memory_if.v". Below is the directory level diagram.

```
-IF
  instruction_memory_if.v
  stage_if.v
+ID
+EX
+MEM
+WB
mips.v
```

Comment: Usually you want to create a file that lists all RTL files (and paths) used in your design and pass this file to the tool. A quick google search revealed that this is also the case for this tool.

Comment: have you tried '-h' qualifier for help? if you did, you should have seen `-I includedir` this, which you could yous on the command line to specify the directories where to search for include files.

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell `iverilog` where to look using the `-I` flag.

In `top.v`:

```
`include "foo.v"

program top;
    initial begin
        foo();
    end
endprogram
```

In `foo/foo.v`:

```
task foo;
    $display("This was printed in the foo module");
endtask
```

Which can be run using the commands:

```
iverilog -g2012 top.v -I foo/
vvp a.out

>>> This was printed in the foo module
```